# How to use a FutureValue inside a (normal) Repository-class

Tags: riverpod

Within a Consumer widget (ChatScreen), a use should be able so send their location. The location information is stored in localUser, which can be retrieved via a provider.
To send the location there is a repository which can be read and a function that can be executed.
I have difficulties accessing the local User Information from the Repository (which has no ref)

```
class ChatScreen extends ConsumerWidget {
  const ChatScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    final messages = ref.watch(chatMessagesProvider);

    return messages.when(
      data: (messages) {
...
InkWell(
                  key: WidgetKey.location,
                  onTap: () {
                    ref.read(chatMessagingRepositoryProvider).sendLocation();
                  },
                  child: MyIcons.chatPin)
```

...
}

```
final chatMessagingRepositoryProvider =
    Provider<ChatMessagingRepository>((ref) => ChatMessagingRepository());

class ChatMessagingRepository {
  Future<void> sendLocation() async {

// This works but IMHO, I should be able to access the localUser via ref.
    final localUser = await LocalUserProfileRepo().getlLocalUser();

    ... send location of user
  }


final localUserProfileRepoProvider = Provider<LocalUserProfileRepo>((ref) => LocalUserProfileRepo());

class LocalUserProfileRepo {
  Future<UserProfile> getlLocalUser() async {
    final localID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    final snap = await FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users').child(localID).get();
    return UserProfile.fromSnap(snap);
  }
  Stream<UserProfile> observelLocalUser()  {
    final localID = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser!.uid;
    return  FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref('users').child(localID).onValue.map((event) => UserProfile.fromSnap(event.snapshot));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `ref` is bound to a `BuildContext`, which I think Riverpod uses to know what providers to create, keep alive and destroy.

You won't be able to request an instance of a provider without a `ProviderScope` (in this case a `BuildContext`) because Riverpod won't know when you will release it, and when to tell you to refresh the value you hold.

You probably have to make your repository into a provider as well. Everything that needs a value from a provider, needs to be a provider. (I believe `ConsumerWidget` wraps a provider to get that `ref`.)

Exception is that you can create your own scope via `ProviderContainer`. This is normally used to run things outside of flutter widgets, either no flutter project, or when you want a provider but there may be no present, i.e handling notifications. This is probably not what you want.